# Cannot instantiate class MetaChecker org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException

Tags: java, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver

Locally this script is working properly but on jenkins server it is showing ( Cannot instantiate class MetaChecker
org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooterForkException ) error with BUILD success.

Comment: The same issue i am also getting when i try to run the cucumber BDD framework with Testng. yesterday it was working fine but today it thrown me a error saying this.Looking for answer

Comment: i fixed it buddy , for me also it's just throwing SurefireBooterForkException because i changed my main class name and forget to change in TestNG.xml file. thats why it thrown me cannot find class path ERROR.